# Adjoints for the restriction of category-valued representations of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, adjoint-functors

**Setup.**
Let $G$ be a group and let $\mathscr{A}$ be a category.
We denote the category of functors from $G$ to $\mathscr{A}$ by $[G, \mathscr{A}]$ and think of these functors as *$\mathscr{A}$-valued representation of $G$*.
(More explicitely, such a representation consists of an object $X$ of $\mathscr{A}$ and a homomorphism of groups from $G$ to $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathscr{A}}(X)$.)

Let now $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.
The inclusion map $i \colon H \to G$ can be regarded as a functor, which then induces a functor
$$
 \operatorname{res}^G_H
 ≔
 i^*
 \colon
 [G, \mathscr{A}]
 \longrightarrow
 [H, \mathscr{A}] \,.
$$
This functor restricts the $\mathscr{A}$-valued representations of $G$ to $\mathscr{A}$-valued representations of $H$.

> **Question**.
> Under what conditions (on $\mathscr{A}$) does the restriction functor $\operatorname{res}^G_H$ admit a left adjoint, resp. a right adjoint?

---

This question is motivated by Exercise 2.1.16 in Tom Leinster’s *Basic Category Theory*, which deals with $[G, \mathrm{Set}]$ and $[G, \operatorname{Vect}(\mathbb{k})]$.

I believe that I understand the following two special cases:

- For every ring $R$ we have for $\mathscr{A} = \operatorname{Mod}(R)$ that $[G, \mathscr{A}] ≅ \operatorname{Mod}(R[G])$.
  We thus have the usual adjunctions
  $$
    R[G] \otimes_{R[H]} (-)
    ⊣
    \operatorname{res}^G_H
    ⊣
    \operatorname{Hom}_{R[H]}(R[G], -) \,.
   $$
- In the case of $\mathscr{A} = \mathrm{Set}$ we have similarly $[G, \mathscr{A}] ≅ G\textrm{-}\mathrm{Set}$ and adjunctions
  $$
    G \times_H (-)
    ⊣
    \operatorname{res}^G_H
    ⊣
    \operatorname{Hom}_H(G, -) \,.
   $$

However, I don’t expect these examples to generalize to an arbitrary category $\mathscr{A}$, as they both rely on some notion of tensor-hom adjuction.

Comment: Well, existence of limits/colimits is enough - the adjoints will be Kan extensions.

Comment: These are subsumed by the notion of Kan extension, for which there are satisfactory existence theorems. I’m sure they’re covered in the book, though maybe later.

Comment: About Kan extensions: In Leinster‘s book Kan extensions are only briefly mentioned in Exercise 6.2.25.

Comment: Example 6.2.8 in Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" discusses this example btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in Emily Riehl’s book “Category Theory in Context”, in particular in Example 6.2.8, as mentioned in the comments. More explicitely, a left adjoint exists if $\mathscr{A}$ is cocomplete, and a right adjoint exists if $\mathscr{A}$ is complete.